# Loop from a specific point in a list of lists Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, flatten

I would like to append to a new list all elements of an existing list of lists after a specific point

```
m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,10],[6,2,1]]
specific point = m[0][2]
newlist = [3,4,5,10,6,2,1]
```

Comment: Are sublists of equal size?

Comment: Yes they are, ex. all length of 2, or all length of 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a conditional in your iteration and only add based on that condition. Once you hit that specific index, make your condition true. Something like this:

```
m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,10],[6,2,1]]
specific_point = (0,2)
newlist = [3,4,5,10,6,2,1]


output = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m[i])):
        if (i,j) < specific_point:
            continue

        output.append(m[i][j])
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This seems like the most rudimentary way, thanks. I will double check if it works when I return home

Comment: You can also roll this into a list-comp, eg: `output = [v for y, r in enumerate(m) for x, v in enumerate(r) if (y, x) >= specific_point]`...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of functional approaches for efficiently iterating over your data.

If sublists are evenly sized, and you know the index from where to begin extracting elements, use `chain` + `islice`:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
n = 3 # Sublist size.
i,j = 0,2
newlist = list(islice(chain.from_iterable(m), i*n + j, None))
```

---

If you don't know the size of your sublists in advance, you can use `next` to discard the first portion of your data.

```
V = chain.from_iterable(m)
next(v for v in V if v == m[i][j])
newlist = list(V)
newlist.insert(m[i][j], 0)
```

This assumes there is no identical value earlier in the sequence.

Comment: These solutions are a bit too advanced, I'm expected to use more basic code. Thank you though

Answer (score 2):

You can directly slice off the remainder of the first target list and then add on all subsequent elements, eg:

```
m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,10],[6,2,1]]
y, x = 0, 2
new_list = m[y][x:] + [v for el in m[y+1:] for v in el]
# [3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

why not flatten the initial list and go from there

`flat_list = [item for sublist in m for item in sublist]`

would return `[1,2,3,4,5,10,6,2,1]` so now you're really on `flat_list[2:]`

Comment: It is in a function in which specific_point serves as an input, i.e. def find_value(m, specific_point)

Comment: right but once you flatten the list all you have to do is compute the first index of the slice, based on the specific point

Comment: Just pointing out, this will create a new flattened list, and then `flat_list[:2]` will create yet another list with the sliced elements.

Comment: @vencaslac You're right, but that only works while specific_point[0] is 0. How about if specific point was [2,1] for example.

Comment: `2xlen(sublist)+1`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers only work for this specific shape of nested list, but it's also possible to create a solution that works with any shape of nested list.

```
def flatten_from(sequence, path=[]):
    start = path.pop(0) if path else 0
    for item in sequence[start:]:
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            yield from flatten_from(item, path)
        else:
            yield item
```

With the example from the question

```
>>> list(flatten_from([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 10], [6, 2, 1]], [0, 2]))
[3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 2, 1]
```

It also works with any shape and level of nesting of the input data

```
m = [[1], [[2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], 8, [9, [10, 11]]]

flatten_from(m, []))       # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
flatten_from(m, [2])       # 8, 9, 10, 11
flatten_from(m, [1, 1, 3]) # 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

This is a bit of a bastard algorithm, though. On one hand, it uses nice functional programming concepts: recursion and yield.

On the other hand it relies on the side effect of mutating the path argument with `list.pop`, so it's not a pure function.

Answer (score 0):

**Below solution will work for your case where your array is restricted to list of list and the size of 'sublist' is consistent throughout i.e "3" in your case**

```
m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,10],[6,2,1]]                                  #input 2D array
a, b = 0, 2                                                     #user input --> specific point a and b
flat_list_m = [item for firstlist in m for item in firstlist]   #flat the 2D list
print (flat_list_m[len(m[0])*a+b:])                             #print from specific position a and b, considering your sublist length is consistent throughout.
```

I hope this helps! :)